# Which map API to draw polygon and export my data that is within boundary?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet, mapbox

I have 5 point datasets that I want to display and be able to filter by fields. I will then be able to hand draw a polygon and export Excel of the data from each dataset within the polygon.

Which web map API should I use? I was looking at mapbox/turf and geojson, but this seems limited.

Comment: Mapbox is built on Leaflet, which I suspect can easily handle what you describe (though saving to Excel from a Javascript application will be a bit of a hack, it is doable). Your question is a bit on the broad side for this format, though, and could you clarify what you mean by limited?

Comment: I was reading about the Turf library for Mapbox and I didn't see a function that would be used for spatial data selection, but maybe I am wrong. I am really hoping there is a webmap out there that demonstrates what I am aiming to do.

Comment: Have a look at the examples in Leaflet or OpenLayers, drawing a polygon and outputting to csv, json, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For drawing the polygons, use [Leaflet Draw](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/leaflet-draw/).

Also, check out the [turf.within function](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_within.html). It takes a set of points and a set of polygons and returns the points that fall within the polygons.

For the excel piece, there are several ways to hack this. The easiest would probably be to setup a simple server endpoint that runs [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) on your geojson and outputs a csv or xls. Another quick alternative would be to parse out the csv in memory, then post the string to a github gist.